# C# Implementation for Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is there a C# implementation for Hyperledger Fabric?
Basically I'm looking for the Nethereum of Hyperledger.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there are no C# (or .NET) Fabric components.

1. The Fabric runtime components (peers, orderers and CAs) are all
   written in Go.
2. Chaincode can be written in Go, Node/JavaScript or Java
3. There are client SDKs in Node/JavaScript, Java, Go and Python

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your taking the time to answer.